# Sql query optimization

Tags: sqlite, query-optimization

I'm trying to optimize an SQL query. The problem is that it is very slow! I'm working with sqlite and with  medium sized datasets(20000row). My sql syntax look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date(A.last_update) as lastUpdate,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bgp_update AS B WHERE date(B.last_update) = date(A.last_update) AND B.validity = 1) AS valid,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bgp_update AS B WHERE date(B.last_update) = date(A.last_update) AND B.validity = 0) AS invalid,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bgp_update AS B WHERE date(B.last_update) = date(A.last_update) AND B.validity = -1) AS notFound
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT last_update FROM bgp_update ORDER BY last_update) AS A WHERE last_update BETWEEN '%var' and '%var2';
```

Below is an example of what do i have:

```
id   |     last_update   |  Validity

48   | 2009-1-6 18:34:38 |  notFound   
47   | 2009-1-6 18:34:38 |  valid   
46   | 2009-1-6 18:34:38 |  valid    
45   | 2009-1-3 18:34:38 |  invalid   
44   | 2009-1-3 18:34:38 |  invalid   
42   | 2009-1-4 18:34:38 |  notFound 
41   | 2009-1-4 18:34:38 |  notFound
48   | 2009-1-4 18:34:38 |  valid
```

And the query result would look like:

```
    Date   |  valid   |  invalid   |    notFound

  2009-1-3 |   0      |     2      |       0
  2009-1-4 |   1      |     0      |       2
  2009-1-6 |   2      |     0      |       1
```

I need this to generate a line graph out of it. The example would be: [line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOmVC.jpg)!

But as I mentioned the query is very slow! How can i make it faster?

:::: 2. EDIT :::::

The previous descriptions I have simplified the problem. My table create statement look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE bgp_update
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    ip VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    mask INTEGER NOT NULL,
    asn INTEGER NOT NULL,
    validity INTEGER NOT NULL,
    last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

As you can see my query only use the last_update and the validity fields.

Comment: Well, you don't specify what the problem is, what the expected results are, table schema, indexes, etc.  We are not mind readers.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll edit the question.

Comment: What does the query optimizer tell you?

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN`, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: `date('2009-1-6 18:34:38')` would be `NULL`, because month and day are not zero-padded. Is your example data really correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sum over case statements, e.g.:

```
select last_update,
  sum(case when validity=1 then 1 else 0 end) valid,
  sum(case when validity=0 then 1 else 0 end) invalid,
  sum(case when validity=-1 then 1 else 0 end) notfound
from bgp_update
where last_update between '1/1/2013' and '1/2/2013'
group by last_update
order by last_update
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/06705/8/0)

Comment: This will have multiple records per day, the `validity` column does not contain `0`/`1`/`-1` values, and the date format is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the date values are in the [proper format](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime) to be understood by the `date` function, you can simply sum over the condition(s) that you want to check (as boolean expressions just return 0 or 1):

```
SELECT date(last_update) AS Date,
       sum(validity = 'valid'   ) AS valid,
       sum(validity = 'invalid' ) AS invalid,
       sum(validity = 'notFound') AS notFound
FROM bgp_update
WHERE last_update BETWEEN ? AND ?
GROUP BY date(last_update)
ORDER BY date(last_update)
```

This query will be efficient if you have an index on the `last_update` column, or even a little bit more efficient if you have a [covering index](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) on the `last_update` and `validity` columns.

Comment: +1 for sum(validity=..) works in place of sum(case when ... end) and looks much cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Nested subqueries sometimes make a query very inefficient. You may consider rewriting the query so that it is using joins.

Second, you may rearrange the joined elements where the table with the fewest records is closest to the beginning of the query. Doing so will reduce the number of records MySQL will have to sort through to retrieve the rows from other tables.

Additionally, you may want to consider using indexes on ID columns and columns of tables that have specific values you are looking into.

If all else fails, you may find that three separate queries may be most efficient.